# How to increase TortoiseGit Activity log size?

Tags: tortoisegit

TortoisGit creates a logfile of its activities. This file ist stored inside the user profile. Basically TGit just writes all output to that file. However it looks like this file has a limited size. On my system the file does not grow over about 200 KB. When new output is added to the file the oldest lines are removed.

Is there a way to increase the size of the file to have a longer history of all activities available?

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseGit -> Settings -> Saved Data -> Action Log -> Max. lines in action log

[image: TortoiseGit Saved Data]